# Standardize Uri between Camera and Gallery Intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, gallery

I'm trying to retrieve URI from gallery and camera in one place (as record in Room database), therefore i need to standardize the access between them. I get it done for the camera by create a file and then retrieve its URI. The URI looks like this:

```
// first URI
content://media/external_primary/images/media/45
```

It works and i can retrieve the image based on that URI after reopening the app.
Here is the code for camera

```
private val launcherIntentCamera = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val bitmap = result?.data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            val uri = savePhotoToExternalStorage(
                requireActivity().contentResolver,
                UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                bitmap
            )
            uri?.let {
                viewModel.updateProfilePic(it.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startTakePhoto() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        launcherIntentCamera.launch(intent)
    }
```

And then i try for gallery intent and what i receive is this:

```
// second URI
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A44
```

Based on what i observe, this URI is temporary. And when i try to retrieve it after reopening the app, it doesnt work.
This is my code

```
private val launcherIntentGallery = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
) { uri ->
    viewModel.updateProfilePic(uri.toString())
}

    private fun startGallery() {
        requireActivity().intent.type = "image/*"
        launcherIntentGallery.launch("image/*")
    }
```

Is there any solution to convert the second URI to the format of first URI so i could retrieve the image when reopening the app?

Comment: Gallery intent? Never heard of. Please show your code.

Comment: `I get it done for the camera by create a file and then retrieve its URI. ` Retrieve? You will use FileProvider to get an uri where the Camera app will write the image to. You will not get a content://media.... uri. Or are you saving a thumbnail bitmap to mediastore then? Show your code please as we do not know what you do.

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot see how you launch your 'gallery' intent. Some relevant code is missing and we still do not know what you do.

Comment: And why didnt you react on what i said about FileProvider and only a thumbnail image?

Comment: `Is there any solution to convert the second URI to the format of first URI so i could retrieve the image when reopening the app?` Reuse possibility does not depend on what you call format of an uri. (You mean used provider). It only depends on if you have permanent uri permission.

Comment: Sorry that doesnt get load before. So (if i understand it correctly), that isnt possible due to temporary permission of the uri. Do you have any reference about how i can get permanent uri permission for image picked from gallery?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the inconvenient, its been added now

Comment: Instead of getContent() or ACTION_GET_CONTENT use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and take persistable uri permission in onActivityResult.